# MySQL - Ordering Values inside a field

Tags: mysql, sorting

Does anyone knows if there's some way to sort values inside a field?

For example:

[image]

To get this result:

[image]

Order by 1 and inside Table2, sort values.

Comment: does table2 value store in this way or produced as result of group function ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @xQbert! And sorry for the duplicate post. Should I turn this off?

Comment: If the prior link solves the problem you can either withdraw this question or  leave it as is indicating the referenced question solves your problem.  if it does't explain what you still need help with! be sure to include examples of where you're struggling.  If it does solve your problem over time this question will get closed referencing the duplicate.  any of the above are perfectly acceptable.  Preference being you indicate your problem is solved and this question can be closed as a duplicate of the one listed.  no harm.  We just try and keep a tidy site and not try and reinvent the wheel.